# Why I am getting an error as use of unresolved identifier 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'?

Tags: swift3

I am using this code in my project.I have imported UIKit and GoogleMaps, but I am getting an error as "use of unresolved identifier CLLocationCoordinate2D". please help me in solving this issue

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    let view = mapView

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You need to `import` the [`CoreLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation) framework for that.

```
import CoreLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing `CLLocationCoordinate2D` you must need to
 `import CoreLocation` 
inside your file then you can able to access all `CoreLocation` framework features.